# Data not being fetched from JSON Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, urlsession

I’ve tried a lot of things and they all don’t seem to work. I have this JSON
`[{"id":"1","name":"Dua Kumayl","location":"IABAT","date":"2019-06-13","Islamic":"Shawwal 8,1440","time":"19:30:00.000000","imageURL":""]`
from this link: http://iabat.org/data.php
and i tried getting the data in Swift using this code:

```
import UIKit
   struct Event: Decodable {
       let id, name, location, date: String
       let Islamic, time, imageURL: String
    }
   class EventsViewController: UIViewController {
         override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()
             let url = "http://iabat.org/data.php"
             guard let urlObj = URL(string: url) else {return}     
              URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj) {(data, 
    response, error) in

        do {
            var Events = try JSONDecoder().decode([Event].self, from: 
       data!)

            for Event in Events {
                print("Hi")
                print(Event)
                print(Event.name)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But for Some Reason, it doesn’t work. And it will also not print anything even if it is a String inside the `for Event in Events` do/catch.

Comment: Can you please post your code for the Events object? Sounds like an error in your model

Comment: Don't `print("error")`, use `print(error)` and see what is going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the `dataTask` with calling `resume()` , also always do `print(error)` to follow errors if any

---

```
 class EventsViewController: UIViewController {
         override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()
             let url = "http://iabat.org/data.php"
             guard let urlObj = URL(string: url) else {return}     
              URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj) {(data, 
    response, error) in

        do {
            var Events = try JSONDecoder().decode([Event].self, from: 
       data!)

            for event in Events {
                print("Hi")
                print(event)
                print(event.name)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
            }
        }.resume() // here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `.resume()` to send the request at the end of the `URLSession.shared.dataTask`.